# Variable disappearing after adding text

Tags: php, curl

I was coding a cURL post request to a website login in order to retrieve a token. The script is meant to login remotely, obtain a token via preg_match and then send a GET request to another url using the preg_matched token.

The token comes in the form of a string e.g. ABCDEFGHIJK. In the second GET request, the token is authorized as: Authorization Bearer: ABCDEFGHIJK

However, upon obtaining the token from the first post request and adding in the words Authorization Bearer, the token disappears.

```
<?php
//Login in Remotely
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'URL');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,           1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     'POST DATA' ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Content-Type: application/json')); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); // On dev server only!
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

//Parse Token
preg_match('#"phoenixAccessToken":"(.*)","phoenixExpiresIn#',$result,$matches);
echo $matches[1]; //This returns ABCDEFGHIJK

//Write authorization (Token returns a 0 now.)
$authorization = 'Authorization Bearer: ' & $matches[1];
echo $authorization; //This returns a 0
?>
```

echo $matches[1] returns the token required perfectly fine, but running echo 'Authorization Bearer: ' & $matches[1]; returns a 0 instead of Authorization Bearer: ABCDEFGHIJK.

Why is this so? Is there anyway to fix the variable so it is static?

Thanks!

Comment: You should use "." instead of "&" when concatenating the string for the $authorization variable.

Comment: Omgosh can't believe i didn't even get that right :(. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use . instead of &.

. just adds it on.